# Using apply() in IIFE

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use apply() within IIFE. I get an error 'intermediate value is not a function' where am I going wrong ?

```
var Person = {
  getFullName : function(firstName, lastName) {
      return firstName + ' ' + lastName;
  }
}

/* IIFE - using apply */

(function(firstName, lastName) {
   getName = function(){
    console.log("From IIFE..");
    console.log(this.getFullName(firstName, lastName));
} 
  getName();
}).apply(Person, ['John', 'Doe']);
```

Plnnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/77db8Mu4i9RXGqt26PAP?p=preview

Comment: apply is for borrow another function. in IIFE, you are dealing with its return type which is undefined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is with `;`, in your code the `Person` object syntax is not terminated, and the IIFE is considered as continuation of that.

Read: [Automatic semicolon insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion)

If you look at external libraries, their IIFE statement starts with a `;`, that is used to escape from this scenario.

Also note that, inside your `getName` function `this` does not refer to the `Person` object, you need to either use a closure variable or pass the value for `this` manually.

```js
var Person = {
  getFullName: function(firstName, lastName) {
    return firstName + ' ' + lastName;
  }
}

/* IIFE - using apply */

;
(function(firstName, lastName) {

  var self = this;
  var getName = function() {
    console.log("From IIFE..");
    console.log(self.getFullName(firstName, lastName));
  }
  getName();
}).apply(Person, ['John', 'Doe']);
```

Comment: Or `getName();` should be `getName.call(this);`.

Comment: Took him half a minute to figure that out... ))

Comment: The use of *self* for *this* does not make sense, since it can be any value at all, including *undefined* in strict mode. What is "self" in this context anyway? It would be better to use `var person = this` then you'd have `person.getFullName(...)` which is much more semantic.